# Value-based color scheme for year-by-year histograms in R

Tags: r, colors, histogram

I'm utilizing ggplot2 in R in order to build histograms of some test results. Right now I have a year-by-year anaylsis of the table Glucose_Results2, which has one Value column and one Year column (and a LOT of rows).

```
Gval2 <- read.csv('Glucose_Results2.csv', sep = ',', header=T)
Gdist = qplot(Value, binwidth=10, data=Gval2, geom="histogram", 
  main="Distribution of Glucose Levels",
  xlab="Glucose Levels in mg/dl",
  ylab="Frequency")
Gval2$Year = factor(Gval2$Year)
Gdist + facet_wrap( ~ Year)
```

This gives me plots for 2005 through 2012. I'm interested in altering the color scheme of these plots to indicate values that fall within the reference range for each year (see below). So for 2005 I want the bins for values between 70 and 110 to be, say, red, whereas the bins outside that range can stay black.

```
>  Gref2
  REFERENCE_LOW REFERENCE_HIGH REFERENCE_YEAR
1            70            110           2005
2            70            110           2006
3            70            110           2007
4            70            110           2008
5            70            110           2009
6            70            100           2010
7            70            100           2011
8            70            100           2012
```

Having only a few weeks' experience in R, I really have no idea how to do this.

Ideally this would include labels for reference high and reference low, or something to the effect of red = within reference range, but I'm not overly concerned about that. What I do want is a solution that reads the above table and selects the appropriate reference ranges based on the year of the histogram (though if it comes down to it, I can enter the numbers manually).

Thank you for reading this and for any responses!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ggplot, to control the color, the easiest way is to get a variable into the data frame which indicates which group it is a part of (the within or outside reference range group). This can be accomplished by a series of steps.  First, for each case, match up the appropriate limits based on the year.

```
Gboth <- merge(Gval2, Gref2, by.x="Year", by.y="REFERENCE_YEAR")
```

This matches, for each row of `Gval2`, the appropriate row of `Gref2` where appropriate is defined by matching the `Year` column in `Gval2` with the `REFERENCE_YEAR` column in `Gref2`.  Then an indicator column can be made using Value and the reference limits. I've made it a labelled factor to make things easier later, but that is not strictly necessary.

```
Gboth$within <- factor(Gboth$REFERENCE_LOW < Gboth$Value & 
                       Gboth$Value <= Gboth$REFERENCE_HIGH,
                       levels = c(FALSE, TRUE),
                       labels = c("Outside reference range",
                                  "Within reference range"))
```

Now I can use this variable to specify the color (really, the fill, since for a histogram colour is the color of the lines around the bars and fill is what fills in the bars). Also, I've translated from `qplot` to full `ggplot` syntax. `qplot` is helpful for transitioning from `plot` commands until you get more familiar with the syntax, but it is not as expressive. If you are learning from scratch, you might as well skip it.

```
ggplot(Gboth, aes(x=Value)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=within), binwidth=10) +
  facet_wrap( ~ Year) +
  scale_x_continuous("Glucose Levels in mg/dl") +
  scale_y_continuous("Frequency") +
  scale_fill_manual("", breaks=c("Outside reference range", 
                                 "Within reference range"),
                    values = c("black", "red")) +
  opts(title = "Distribution of Glucose Levels")
```

For some made up values for `Gval2`, I get a graph that looks like

[image]